# Python - Django - 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, django, file

I'm making the user upload a txt file and then submitting it so i can do some work on that file in one of my views.

I had some problems with that but with help of the community is now at least recognizing the POST method in my form.

What is happening is that my view is failing in reading the file. This is me debugging my view:

[image]

As you can see the do_some_work method checks for a POST method and if it is then file that comes with the request, that is a TXT file and then split the lines in that file.

Well this is not working. When i reach that line i get the:

```
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'split'
```

So i don't know what could be wrong.

This is my form:

```
<form  action="{% url "do_some_work" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="some_file">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I will appreciate any help with this. If you need more information just let me know
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to split the file object. You can only split the content of the file. A file object has different means to read and manipulate its content than a plain string.

The `InMemoryUploadedFile` acts as a proxy for Python's `file` object. To get a list of individual lines, you can use the [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines) method:

```
lines = data.readlines()
```

If you just need to iterate through the individual lines, you can iterate the file object itself:

```
for line in data:
    # do something with line
```